# Instantiate unique_ptr to derived class from vector of base class where derived class has been stored

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance, unique-ptr

Consider following piece of code:

```
struct  Fruit
{
   Fruit() {}
   virtual ~Fruit() {}       
   std::string name;
};

struct Banana : public Fruit
{
   std::string color;
};

struct Pineapple : public Fruit
{
   int weight;
};
```

here is my main() :

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Fruit>> product;
    product.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Banana>(new Banana)); //product[0] is a Banana
    product.emplace_back(new Pineapple);

    // I need to acess the "color" member of product[0]
    std::unique_ptr<Banana> b = std::move(product[0]); // this doesn't work, why?
    auto c = b->color;
}
```

in `product[0]` I store a unique_ptr to Banana, why can't I assign it to a banana unique_ptr ?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that `product[0]` points to a `Banana` and not some other `Fruit`. If you are sure about that, you can tell the compiler, by way of a cast. E.g.`std::unique_ptr<Banana> b{static_cast<Banana*>(product[0].release())};`

Comment: with release() my product[0] is lost. I don't want this to happend since I plan to use it again. Is there another way?

Comment: It would be similarly lost with `std::unique_ptr<Banana> b = std::move(product[0]);`, if it were to compile, so I assumed that's what you wanted. If you didn't mean to take ownership out of the vector, make it `auto b = static_cast<Banana*>(product[0].get());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want ownership transfer, so cast only the pointer:

```
auto& banana = dynamic_cast<Banana&>(*product[0]);
auto c = banana.color;
```

`dynamic_cast` might be replaced by `static_cast` if you are really sure that `Fruit`is really a `Banana`.
In case your are wrong, `static_cast` would lead to UB whereas you can check validity with `dynamic_cast` (exception with cast to reference or null pointer with cast to pointer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly cast, since that first product can be any fruit... The compiler doesn't know whether this fruit is a Banana or a Pineapple.

As @IgorTandetnik said, you could do:

```
std::unique_ptr<Banana> b{static_cast<Banana*>(product[0].release())};
```

where [`release()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/release/) is used, along with [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

<kbd>[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/wa4Dqv)</kbd>

Note: You can't fall back to using `auto` for b, since the compiler will choose `struct Fruit` as the type, in order to be prepared for any subclass.

Comment: with release() my product[0] is lost forever. I don't want this to happend since I plan to use it again. Is there another way?

Comment: @Gaetan there should only ever be **one** `unique_ptr` pointing to a given object. If it's a local `std::unique_ptr<Banana> b` then it can't be a `std::unique_ptr<Fruit>` element of `product`. Maybe you only want a `Banana * b`?

Comment: oh yes, with `Banana* b´  everything works fine. thanks. So unique_ptr can never be instantiate with an existing unique_ptr without setting the this existing one to nullptr, right?

Comment: @Gaetan `unique_ptr` is **unique**, i.e. it cannot share ownership. That's why it's not possible to copy it for example, so yes.